# Azure search query to filter JSON values

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to frame Azure search query. The field type is collection(Edm.String) in Azure search index. This is how my JSON data to be filtered looks like : ["A","B"].

When I try to filter using the query Alphabet in 'A' it brings all the entries that has "A" in it. But when I try to frame the same query in my code like  "'A' in Alphabet" it throws an exception stating:

> "Invalid expression: Expression contains an unsupported OData language feature. Please revise your query and try again.
>   Parameter name: $filter".

Is there any other Azure query which I can use to filter my JSON data?

Note : I could not use eq as my field is multi valued and eq can handle only single values.

Comment: So do you want to make up a filter expression that will be able to filter results that has collection with multi values such as ["A","B"] instead of just ["A"]  ?

Comment: Yes. My filed is a JSON collection that has values like ["A"] ,["A","B"], ["C","A","E"]. I need a query to get A from all the three.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter a collection that need to include multiple values, ie , you want to query all result whose collection all has "A" and "B" try the filter expression below :

Let's assume your collection field name is "alphabet"

```
$filter=alphabet/any(s: s eq 'A') and alphabet/any(s: s eq 'B')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I need to compare against collection of string. In other words I want to query 'A' and fetch all result that has A in it.

Like comparing 'A' against my JSON collection in ["A"] , ["A","B","C"] and so on. Currently eq is not able to query against multi valued field.

Comment: I see , let assume there are 3  docs in your index, and the collection data is :
["A","B","C"] 
["B","B","C"]
["C","A","C"]
and the collection name file name is "alphabet", if you want to filter the result that collection contains "A", pls try the expression below :

$filter=alphabet/any(s: s eq 'A')

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to use search.ismatch query like search.ismatch('A,B','Alphabet','simple','any'). So the result will have search results of all the records having either A or B or both.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-odata-filter-orderby-syntax